# How to tell npm where my project is?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2017, npm-install

When I create a new project in Visual Studio 2017, it creates the directory as

```
C:\Users\x\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MyApp
```

which contains the solution file, .vs hidden folder and another folder named the same as my project.

```
 C:\Users\x\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MyApp\MyApp
```

Therefore is the root directory for all my actual code files for that project. However, when I try to do

```
npm install
```

It looks at

```
C:\Users\x\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MyApp
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\x\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MyApp\MyApp.
```

I am unsure how to fix this, please advise! Thank you

Comment: ever figure this one out?

Comment: yes, sorry! check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug... either re-select the default project in PMC or type cd ProjName first (replacing ProjName with your project name)